# Dockerfile - exec form of ENTRYPOINT and shell form of CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am looking at Docker's [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) to understand what would be behavior of `ENTRYPOINT` defined in exec form and `CMD` defined in shell form.

The example in the docs only shows something like `exec_entry p1_entry /bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd` which does not tell me anything.

For example, what if we had:

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS '-XX:+UseG1GC -Xms512m -Xmx1536m'
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar
```

Would the problem with signal propagation exist here (in other words, would any extra subshell be spawned here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If either `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` are not JSON arrays, they are interpreted as strings and converted to a length-3 array `["/bin/sh", "-c", "..."]`.
2. The resulting two lists are concatenated.

So in your example, the final command list would be

```json
["java", "/bin/sh", "-c", "$JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar"]
```

or in Bourne shell syntax

```bash
java /bin/sh -c '$JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar'
```

This passes the shell interpreter `/bin/sh` as an argument to `java`; that almost certainly is not what you intend.

If the `CMD` is anything other than a complete command, it must use the JSON-array syntax, which in turn means it can't use any shell features and it can't expand environment variable references.  This would include both the "container-as-command" pattern where `ENTRYPOINT` is the command to run and `CMD` its arguments, and the antipattern you show here where `ENTRYPOINT` is the interpreter only (and you have to repeat the `-jar app.jar` option in a `docker run` command override).

I prefer a setup where `CMD` is always a complete shell command.  If you have an `ENTRYPOINT` at all, it's a script that does some startup-time setup and then runs `exec "$@"` to run the command passed as arguments.  This can accept either form of `CMD`.

```bash
# ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]  # optional
CMD java $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar         # in a single shell-format CMD
```

Comment: `CMD java $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar` this is a bad idea because it messes with signal propagation to the app. https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/

Comment: Does `CMD exec java ...` resolve that?  You still need it in shell form to do variable expansion, but the `exec` should cause the shell to replace itself with the JVM as pid 1.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but I finally figured out what is the point of `/bin/sh -c` in this use-case. We can for example use [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) as an entrypoint

`ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--"]`

and then a shell for of CMD, but we need to use `exec` in order to replace a subshell, that is

`CMD exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar`